# DataTable in Wpf is Unknown

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable, wpfdatagrid

I've a datagridview which should be fill from a sqlserver Table.

```
        SqlConnection SqlConnectionInstance = new SqlConnection(WinLogin.connectinStringSecure);
        SqlConnectionInstance.Open();
        SqlCommand sqlCommandInstance = new SqlCommand("Select * From T_Kala", SqlConnectionInstance);
        SqlDataAdapter SqlDataAdapterInstance = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * From T_Kala", SqlConnectionInstance);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("Employee");
```

but visual studio can not Identify the **DataTable**!

Error :

> The type or namespace name 'DataTable' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Possibly a silly question, but I take it you have `using System.Data;` but the problem persists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check for the `System.Data` reference in the references list. It should be added by default, but it could have been removed.

If it exists, make sure you have the `using System.Data;` declaration at the top of your file.